# How to show the labels in a pie chart using d3 and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm new to both reactjs and d3js and was trying to create a pie chart using d3 in a reactjs website. I wanted to create a pie chart that shows the labels in the pie chart as tooltips and also an arrow pointing to the slices with their corresponding labels exactly like this [example](http://d3pie.org/#generator-start-pie3).

I have created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-d3-pie-chart-djx8y) to further demonstrate where I'm stuck right now. As you can see the values are being shown in the slices but I want the labels as well just like in the example above. I would be grateful if someone can please help me with this one.

This is the code that I have created so far.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const Pie = props => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const createPie = d3
    .pie()
    .value(d => d.value)
    .sort(null);
  const createArc = d3
    .arc()
    .innerRadius(props.innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(props.outerRadius);
  const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  const format = d3.format(".2f");

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = createPie(props.data);
    const group = d3.select(ref.current);
    const groupWithData = group.selectAll("g.arc").data(data);

    groupWithData.exit().remove();

    const groupWithUpdate = groupWithData
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    const path = groupWithUpdate
      .append("path")
      .merge(groupWithData.select("path.arc"));

    path
      .attr("class", "arc")
      .attr("d", createArc)
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => colors(i));

    const text = groupWithUpdate
      .append("text")
      .merge(groupWithData.select("text"));

    text
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${createArc.centroid(d)})`)
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("font-size", 10)
      .text(d => format(d.value));
  }, [props.data]);

  return (
    <svg width={props.width} height={props.height}>
      <g
        ref={ref}
        transform={`translate(${props.outerRadius} ${props.outerRadius})`}
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default Pie;
```

Comment: You need to append `text` elements with the labels, just as you would any other data-bound element.  Here is an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799).  There are numerous others on bl.ocks.org

Comment: @varontron I tried adding append title after the text elements like the examples shown in the block website but the whole pie chart disappears. Can you show in sandbox where to exactly append the titles to show the labels?